# How to add multiple performers to event schema with seomatic

Tags: plugin-seomatic

I am adding [event schema](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event) to an entry page. I have offer and date properties working well based on https://nystudio107.com/blog/tips-for-using-seomatic-effectively

This is working for offers

```
{% if entry.soldOut == '1' %}
  {% set availability = 'http://schema.org/SoldOut' %}
{% else %}
  {% set availability = 'http://schema.org/InStock' %}
{% endif %}
{% set offersJsonLd = seomatic.jsonLd.create({
    'type': 'Offer',
    'price': entry.eventPrice,
    'priceCurrency': 'GBP',
    'validFrom': entry.postDate|date("Y-m-d"),
    'url': entry.url,
    'availability': availability,
}, false) %}
{% do mainEntity.offers(offersJsonLd) %}
```

I can't work out the correct approach for performers though. I have a Matrix field for performers with two fields performerType and performerName

I have tried this

```
{% set performerJsonLd = seomatic.jsonLd.create(
  {% for block in entry.performers .all() %}
    {
    'type': block.performerType,
    'name': block.performerName,
    },
  {% endfor %}
  false) %}
{% do mainEntity.performer(performerJsonLd) %}
```

and

```
{% set performersAndTypes %}
  {% for block in entry.performers .all() %}
    {
      '@type': '{{ block.performerType }}',
      'name': '{{ block.performerName }}',
    }{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endset %}
{% set performerJsonLd = seomatic.jsonLd.create(
  performersAndTypes,
  false) %}
{% do mainEntity.performer(performerJsonLd) %}
```

but get errors for both.

What would the correct approach be to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out some of the examples here? [Annotated JSON-LD Structured Data Examples](https://nystudio107.com/blog/annotated-json-ld-structured-data-examples) -- specifically the **devMode.fm Episode Page** example shows adding an array of "actors" and "mentions" to the RadioEpisode type.

The key concept is that anything that can be a schema.org type can also be an array of that type as well.

Answer (score 3):

I hadn't seen those examples but it is bookmarked now.

I've adapted your example as below and it's all working. Thanks @andrew.welch

```
{% set performersArray = [] %}
{% for block in entry.performers .all() %}
  {% set performersArray = performersArray | merge([seomatic.jsonLd.create({
      'type': block.performerType,
      'name': block.performerName,
  }, false)]) %}
{% endfor %}
{% do mainEntity.performer(performersArray) %}
```

Comment: excellently done!